# Is `AccountInfo::realloc` limited to 10kb across all accounts or per account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Is the 10kb limitation of `AccountInfo::realloc` a per account limitation? Namely, can you increase the size of multiple accounts by 10kb in the same instruction or is the 10kb increase limitation shared between all accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`realloc()`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/f44fcd18800219a1febfce7e2f90a657f907b676/sdk/program/src/account_info.rs#L147) is implemented on `AccountInfo`. So per-account